# PhantomJS render of individual frame not working properly

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/) as a method of creating a local copy of a website, I have a function which traverses the frame structure of a website and grabs the frame contents as it goes, storing it in a global array. This part is working fine at the moment, the problem is:

At each step I am attempting to convert the frame to a Base64 encoded image using

```
var temp =  require('webpage').create();
temp.content = currpage.frameContent; //set the temp page to be the current frame
var b64 = temp.renderBase64('png');
```

If I simply export `currpage.frameContent` to a file and open it, I can see it's contents as well as open it in a browser and see that it does indeed display what it is supposed to (ads, for the most part).

Although, the `b64` variable has no value and there are no errors popping up when running the program.

I should also note that `b64` doesn't *always* have no value, sometimes I do indeed get a proper rendering of the frame, depending on the site I am scraping.

Comment: how `frame.Content` looks like in such cases? and does `render` function renders anything?

Comment: It is a standard html enclosed site, opens in a browser and everything. I remove the script tages from within it beforehand since they aren't needed anymore.   Render does not render anything in these cases.  If I output the frame contents to an html file and run a separate instance of phantomjs, open the page and render it's contents it works just fine. Unfortunately, I dont think that will be a potential solution in the context of what I'm trying to do

Comment: The weirdest part is that temp.content has exactly what I want in it, but it just isnt being rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while the issue has been uncovered, although we are switching directions with the project, I will post how to fix what my problem was.

In order to get the temp to render, all I had to do was set temp's viewport.

```
temp.viewportSize = {
    width: 480,
    height: 800
};
```